# Merging diff tables between 2 Databases sqlite

Tags: python, database, sqlite

Ok, so I have a program that I wrote (some user control automation), it has a Database - it's running just now on one of my Server, and it's version is 1.0.

In the last time I added some upgrades to the tool (so it's version is 1.5).

what is my problem - 
In version 1, the tool's Database looks like -

`table a
table b
table c`

In version 1.5 I added some more tables to the database - 
`table a
table b
table c
table d
table e`

What I need?

I want to add all the new tables from version 1.5 to version 1's Database, without loosing all the production data in the production database.

just moving all the new tables between the new database and the old - to the old database. (diff between databases and push all the diff tables to the old one).

I have an Idea how to do that in python, something like - 

`- Get list of tables from the new Database
- Get list of tables from the old Database
- Get tables diff
- push manually table after table from the new to old`

but before I am starting to write some code to do that, maybe there is some easier way to do that? because I am pretty sure thats not only my problem.

is there a way to marge the databases that way ?

Sqlite 3 database

p.s.
Don't know what is the proper title for the question, so if someone can advise something it can be great :)

Comment: Just tables? Do you want to migrate their rows as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to add missing tables - without migrating rows and columns for already existing tables, you can achieve it this way.

1. Make a backup before running any stackoverflow tips through your production database. ;-)
2. Dump your new database into the sql file.

```
$ sqlite3 your_new_db.db
sqlite> .output dump.sql
sqlite> .dump
```

3. Next, replace all `CREATE TABLE` occurrences with `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`, and filter out all other SQL commands.

```
grep 'CREATE TABLE' dump.sql | sed -e 's|CREATE\ TABLE|CREATE\ TABLE\ IF\ NOT\ EXISTS|g' > add_missing_tables.sql
```

4. Once you're happy with the output, import it to your old database.

```
cat add_missing_tables.sql | sqlite3 your_old_db.db
```